# Unable to render collection of items into Blazor forms

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'd like to render a table with inline editing of a single property in my Blazor (server-side) application. Each item in the collection should render row in a table wrapped with an `EditForm` tag so I get model binding of each collection along with an `EventCallback` for each "Edit" or "Delete" operation.

Here is my parent component which includes an `IEnumerable<GroupModel>`:

#### Parent Component:

```
@{
    if (_allGroups.Any())
    {
        <div>
            <table class="table" id="allGroups">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Modify</th>
                <th scope="col">Group Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Associated (#)</th>
                <th scope="col">Date Added</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in _allGroups)
            {
                <EditGroupItem SaveItem="@SaveItemAsync" DeleteItem="@DeleteItemAsync" GroupItem="@item"/>
            }
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    }
}
```

#### EditGroupItem component:

```
@using MyProject.Common.Models
<EditForm Model="GroupItem">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" @onclick="(() => SaveItem.InvokeAsync(GroupItem))"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" @onclick="(() => DeleteItem.InvokeAsync(GroupItem))"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <InputText type="text" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@GroupItem.GroupName"></InputText>
        </td>
        <td>@GroupItem.PasswordsAssociatedTo</td>
        <td>@GroupItem.DateAdded.ToString("d")</td>
    </tr>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter] public GroupModel GroupItem { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<GroupModel> DeleteItem { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<GroupModel> SaveItem { get; set; }
}
```

Given the code above, the table never shows each component instance created by the `@foreach` statement.

I tried removing the `<EditForm>` tags and just use a regular `<input>` instead of the Blazor `<InputText>` tag, and the component is rendered with the parameters just fine. However, my callback doesn't pass back the edited value from `@GroupItem.GroupName`.

So the above code doesn't render correctly and the other option I tried doesn't give back the edited object.

Any ideas on how I can achieve inline editing of an object passed into a Blazor component? Or maybe another way altogether?

Comment: could you show changes without EditForm. I tried replicating without form and it is working.

Comment: when you say it's working, are you able to get the callback to send the model back to the parent object?

Comment: Yes I am getting callback in parent. I have added what I did in an answer.

Comment: Yes, your example works. For the benefit of others, perhaps you can omit the code altogether and indicate the fix specifically. The only change I could see (and made myself) was to use `@bind=` instead of `@bind-Value` and it works now without the `EditForm` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in Blazor. A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr you can wrap a table with a form o you can place the form inside td.

```
<tr>

    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" @onclick="(() => SaveItem.InvokeAsync(GroupItem))"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" @onclick="(() => DeleteItem.InvokeAsync(GroupItem))"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <EditForm Model="GroupItem">
            <InputText type="text" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@GroupItem.GroupName"></InputText>
        </EditForm>
    </td>
    <td>@GroupItem.PasswordsAssociatedTo</td>
    <td>@GroupItem.DateAdded.ToString("d")</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

### EditGrp

```
    <tr>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" @onclick="(() => SaveItem.InvokeAsync(GroupItem))"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" @onclick="(() => DeleteItem.InvokeAsync(GroupItem))"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@GroupItem.GroupName" />
    </td>
    <td>@GroupItem.PasswordsAssociatedTo</td>
    <td>@GroupItem.DateAdded.ToString("d")</td>
</tr>

@code {
    [Parameter] public GroupModel GroupItem { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<GroupModel> DeleteItem { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<GroupModel> SaveItem { get; set; }


    public class GroupModel
    {
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public string PasswordsAssociatedTo { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }

}
```

### Parent

```
 <div>
    <table class="table" id="allGroups">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Modify</th>
            <th scope="col">Group Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Associated (#)</th>
            <th scope="col">Date Added</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in _allGroups)
        {
             <EditGroupItem SaveItem="@SaveItemAsync" DeleteItem="@DeleteItemAsync" GroupItem="@item">
             </EditGroupItem>
        }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

@code
{

    public List<EditGroupItem.GroupModel> _allGroups = new List<EditGroupItem.GroupModel>()
    {
        new EditGroupItem.GroupModel{GroupName = "one", PasswordsAssociatedTo = "test", DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow},
        new EditGroupItem.GroupModel{GroupName = "two", PasswordsAssociatedTo = "test 2", DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(10)}

    };

    public void SaveItemAsync(EditGroupItem.GroupModel model)
    {

    }

    public void DeleteItemAsync(EditGroupItem.GroupModel model)
    {

    }


}
```